# JavaScript not working with dynamically loaded gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, dynamic

I'm using this javascript on several pages to filter gridview results based on the input, and it works perfectly. However, on the one page where I'm dynamically generating columns for the gridview it does not work.

I tried using $('.btnSearch').on('click','.gvSearch', function (e) {...
,but that also didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.lblSearch').css('display', 'none');

$('.btnSearch').click(function (e) {
    // Hide No records to display label.
    $('.lblSearch').css('display', 'none');

    //Hide all the rows.
    $(".gvSearch" + " tr:has(td)").hide();

    var iCounter = 0;

    //Get the search box value
    var sSearchTerm = $('.txtSearch').val();

    //if nothing is entered then show all the rows.
    if (sSearchTerm.length == 0) {
        $(".gvSearch" + " tr:has(td)").show();
        return false;
    }
    //Iterate through all the td.
    $(".gvSearch" + " tr:has(td)").children().each(function () {
        var cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        //Check if data matches
        if (cellText.indexOf(sSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            $(this).parent().show();
            iCounter++;
            return true;
        }
    });
    if (iCounter == 0) {
        $('.lblSearch').css('display', '');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})
});
```

Comment: When exactly do you generate the columns?

Comment: There are 3 asp buttons representing tabs. On each button click a dynamic gridview is generated.

Comment: You're not showing what the "btnSearch" class is applied to, but this might explain it: If the buttons are not added until the dynamic generation occurs then they don't have the event handler attached since it's done at document ready.  Try adding them to the document with a ".btnSearch" filter

Comment: The 'btnSearch' class is applied to a single button, which when clicked executes the code above. None of the buttons are dynamically generated, just the gridview which has the class 'gvSearch'

Comment: This looks like it should work, which suggests the issue could be in your dynamic generation.  obMCVE